# Python High Low Game Reversed Optimized

Tags: python

```
def highlowR():
    play_again = 1
    while play_again==1:
        ct = 0
        guess = 50
        x = 0
        ans = ""
        print "Lets play a game. \nThink of a number between 1 and 100.\n"
        while ans!="c":
            temp0 = 0
            temp1 = 0
            print "I guess %d" %guess
            ans = raw_input("Am I too (h)igh, too (l)ow, or (c)orrect? \n")
            if ans=="h":
                temp0 = guess/2
                temp1 = guess%2
                guess = temp0 + temp1
            elif ans=="l":
                temp0 = guess/2
                temp1 = guess%2
                guess = guess + temp0 + temp1
            elif ans=="c":
                print "I got it! It only took me %d guesses." %ct
            else:
                print "I didn't quite understand what you meant there."
            ct = ct+1
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes = 1, No = 0: ")
        print""
    print "Thanks for playing!"
highlowR()
```

I almost have a running reverse high low game but I cant figure out how to change the math in my if statements to optimize my results. It works if the number to be guessed is 1... but I cant figure out what to do so that I can optimize my results. Any help?

Comment: You need to read up on how to do a binary search. You don't need your results "optimized", you need them to actually work. You can start keeping track of what the absolute maximum and minimum possibilities are at any point in your algorithm, and then base each guess on that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you're trying to do with your temp0 and temp1. Much better to keep the min and max in memory. Something like this should work:

```
def highlowR():
    play_again = 1
    while play_again==1:
        ct = 0
        max = 10
        min = 0
        guess = 0
        x = 0
        ans = ""
        print "Lets play a game. \nThink of a number between 1 and %d.\n"%max
        while ans!="c":
            if (max+min)/2 == guess:
                print "I think you lied to me at some point. The answer is definitely %d" %guess
                break
            guess = (max+min)/2
            print "I guess %d" %guess
            ans = raw_input("Am I too (h)igh, too (l)ow, or (c)orrect? \n")
            if ans=="h":
                max = guess
            elif ans=="l":
                min = guess
            elif ans=="c":
                print "I got it! It only took me %d guesses." %ct
            else:
                print "I didn't quite understand what you meant there."
            ct = ct+1
        play_again = input("Would you like to play again? Yes = 1, No = 0: ")
        print""
    print "Thanks for playing!"
highlowR()
```